# leaflet map changes with respect to selections in dc.js charts

Tags: leaflet, underscore.js, dc.js

I want to implement map overlay using leaflet. In the following code mainmap is the baselayer; heat and markLayer are two heat maps. I want to link only the 'heat' layer to my dc.js charts. The two overlays are successfully working but the 'heat' layer is not changing according to selections in the chart.

I am unable to figure out where I am wrong. My problem is that I am unable to link the dcCharts (array of dc charts) with leaflet map heatlayer. The visualization on the map remains the same even after selections.

```
`var mainmap;
  var heat;
  mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
  mainmap = L.tileLayer(
      'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 15,
      });

    //1st HeatMap
  var geoData = [];
  _.each(allDim.top(Infinity), function(d) {
      geoData.push([d["lat"], d["long"], 1]);
        });
   heat = L.heatLayer(geoData,{
      radius: 10,
      blur: 20, 
      maxZoom: 1,
    });

   //2nd HeatMap
    var geoDataa =[];
    _.each(allDimm.top(Infinity), function(d){

      geoDataa.push([d["lat"], d["long"], 1]);
    });


  var markerLayer = L.heatLayer(geoDataa, {
    radius: 10,
      blur: 20, 
      maxZoom: 1,
});



  map = L.map('map',{
  layers: [mainmap, heat, markerLayer]
});
  map.setView([22.97, 100.65], 4);

  var baseMaps = {
    "BaseMap": mainmap
    };

var overlayMaps = {
    "heat": heat,
    "markerLayer": markerLayer 
};


 mainmap.addTo(map);

 function drawMap()
  {
    heat.addTo(map);
    mainmap.addTo(map);
  }   
  L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
  drawMap();

  //Update the heatmap if any dc chart get filtered

  _.each(dcCharts, function (dcChart) {
    dcChart.on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
          map.removeLayer(layer)
        }); 
        console.log("Yes, I am called");
    drawMap();
    });
  dc.renderAll();

}); `
```

Comment: I missed this because the tag was wrong - please use [dc.js] for questions related to the javascript charting library. [dc] is unrelated. It's a great question and someone recently asked how to add this feature to dc.leaflet.js. Hope that happens! Lmk if you still need help.

Comment: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js/issues/38

Comment: leaflet heatmap works with dc.js library. I used the underscore.js to and wrote the function  dcChart.on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
          map.removeLayer(layer)
        }); where the layer is one of the heatmaps. So this map changes with the charts selection/filtering. But when I use two heat map, I am unable to integrate the overlapping heatmap and the map goes blank on selection of any chart. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle demonstrating the problem, and add it to your question? It would be difficult for me to guess what is going wrong without seeing it run.